# Legendre Polynomials Triple Product

Tags: integration, orthogonal-polynomials

I have to solve the following integral:

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1} \left(x^2 -1\right)^3 P_k(x)\,P_l(x)\, P_m(x) \;dx
\end{align}
where $P_{k,l,m}$ are Legendre Polynomials

The triple product
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1} P_k(x)\,P_l(x)\, P_m(x) \;dx = 2 \begin{pmatrix} k & l & m \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^2
\end{align}
using the special case of $3j$ symbol form
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} k & l & m \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
    &= (-1)^s \sqrt{(2s-2k)! (2s-2l)! (2s-2m)! \over (2s+1)!}
        {s! \over (s-k)! (s-l)! (s-m)!}
        \\ & \mbox{for $2s=k+l+m$ even} \\[3pt]
\begin{pmatrix} k & l & m \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
    &= 0
        \quad\mbox{for $2s=k+l+m$ odd} \\
\end{align}

I'm sure you should be able to solve this by doing integration by parts but can't seem to get it to work. Any tips?

So using the answer below I think you get the following for step 1 of 3

\begin{multline}
 \int_{-1}^{1}(x^2-1)^3 P_k P_l P_m 
 = \overbrace{(x^2-1)^3\frac{(P_{k+1} - P_{k-1})}{2k+1} P_l P_m \Big]_{-1}^1}^\text{ = 0}\\
-\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{(P_{k+1} - P_{k-1})}{2k+1}(x^2-1)^2\Big( 
6xP_l P_m \\
+  (1+l) P_m(P_{l+1} - P_{l-1})  + 
(1+m) P_l(P_{m+1} - P_{m-1}) \Big) \; dx\\ 
\end{multline}

Not sure if the formula for integration works as I think the $6xP_lP_m$ term might cause problems?

Comment: Has anyone seen discussion of this kind of problem for four polynomials in the integrand?

i.e. \int_{-1}^1 P_m(x)P_n(x)P_l(x)P_p(x) dx

Comment: "Special case of $3j$ symbol form" is not looking so user friendly... How did you get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way to approach this is as follows,
note that 
\begin{align}
(x^2 -1 ) = \frac{P_2 - 2}{3} 
\end{align}
You can then use the following definition
\begin{align}
P_kP_l = \sum_{m=|k-l|}^{k+l} 
\begin{pmatrix}
k & l & m \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^2
(2m+1)P_m
\end{align}
This allows the integral to be written as follows
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1} (x^2-1)^3P_iP_jP_k \; dx &=  \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{9}\left(P_2^3 + . . .-8 \right) P_i P_j P_k \; dx
\end{align}
The most difficult term to deal with is the $ P_2^3 P_i P_j P_k$ 
\begin{align}
P_2^3 P_i P_j P_k &= \sum_{m=0}^{4}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 & m \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^2 (2m+1)P_m P_2 P_i P_j P_k \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{4}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 & m \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^2 (2m+1)
\sum_{n=|m-2|}^{m+2}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & m & n \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^2 (2n+1)P_n P_i P_j P_k \\
&= 
\sum_{m=0}^{4}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 & m \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^2 (2m+1)
\sum_{n=|m-2|}^{m+2}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & m & n \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^2 (2n+1)
\sum_{l=|n-i|}^{n+i}
\begin{pmatrix}
n & i & l \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^2 (2l+1)
P_l P_j P_k
\end{align}
Which can then make use of the usual triple integral.
All other terms can be solved for in a similar manner.

Comment: Hi! I think this approach may help  me too: do you know of any analogous definitions for order 1 Legendre polynomials to reduce a product of two into a linear sum? It would be really useful right now!

Answer (score 2):

You could integrate one of the $P_k(x)$ and take the derivative of the rest. The power of $(1-x^2)$ gets reduce by the fact that
$$\partial_x P_l(x) = \frac{(1+l) [ P_{l+1}(x)-x P_l(x) ]}{x^2-1}.$$
You have to apply partial integration a few times and you will generate a bunch of Legendre triple product.

Comment: Think this way will work, thanks for the help.

Comment: Just wondering, where did you get the formula above?

Comment: @Matt: I hope it is correct. I simply looked it up [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5BLegendreP%5Bl%2Cx%5D%2Cx%5D).

Comment: thanks for info, I think it might be wrong, wikipedia has a different one (which I think is also wrong) as I worked out the following:
\begin{align}
P'_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{(1-x^2)(2n+1)} \left[P_{n+1} - P_{n-1} +c \right] 
\end{align} 
Which works when I do the differentiation.

Comment: got it from the following definition:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ (1-x^2) \frac{d}{ dx} P_n(x) \right] + n(n+1)P_n(x) = 0
\end{align}

Comment: The definitions might be equivalent when using the recurrence relation?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I've got an answer for it now. I think when you integrate multiple times the recurrence relations drop a constant which can't be ignored.