# Integral over triple Legendre polynomials involving derivatives

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, legendre-polynomials

I know the integral over the triple product of Legendre polynomials (see [Legendre Polynomials Triple Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262973/legendre-polynomials-triple-product/264110#264110)), which reads

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1} P_k(x)\,P_l(x)\, P_m(x) \;\mathrm{d}x = 2 \begin{pmatrix} k & l & m \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^2
\end{align}

where the big parenthesis is Wigner-3$j$ symbol.

But I encountered a similar integral in a physics problem
\begin{align}
I=\int_{-1}^{1} P_k'(x)\,P_l'(x)\, P_m(x) (1-x^2)\;\mathrm{d}x 
\end{align}
where the prime $'$ means the derivative with respect to $x$. I don't know is there a similar closed form solution of the above integral?

I tried using the recurrence relation
\begin{equation}
(1-x^2)P_n'(x)=(n+1)[xP_n(x)-P_{n+1}(x)]
\end{equation}
and the integral becomes
\begin{equation}
I=(k+1)(l+1)\int_{-1}^1 [xP_k(x)-P_{k+1}(x)][xP_{l}(x)-P_{l+1}(x)]P_m(x) \frac{1}{1-x^2}\;\mathrm{d} x
\end{equation}
It seems not helpful.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found there indeed exists a closed form solution which reads

\begin{align}
I=\int_{-1}^{1} P_k'(x)\,P_l'(x)\, P_m(x) (1-x^2)\;\mathrm{d}x =
[k(k+1)+l(l+1)-n(n+1)] \begin{pmatrix} k & m & l \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^2
\end{align}